# Get SSL version from smtp server in Javamail

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, smtpclient

I recently upgraded to new JavaMail 1.4 and i can't connect to `smtp.gmail.com` over ssl.

This line works before javamail upgrade:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "ssl");
```

Now it need to look like this:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "sslv3");
```

or

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "tlsv1");
```

This doesn't work:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "tls");
```

My question is:

1. Why previous version could work?
2. How to get SSL version from server
   so i could switch to it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave it out. Java will figure it out.

Those protocol names should be in uppercase as far as I know,

Comment: This work as you say. But i newer version i get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSL